# (C++) How do I call on a structure from another file?

Tags: c++, database, struct, structure

I'm a beginner at programming, and I'm making an RPG sort of game in C++.

Currently I only have two files in use in my program, one file that serves as a database for various enemies in the game, and the other which runs the program and does everything else.

The "database" has a structure template:

```
struct monster
{
    string monsterName;
    int maxMonsterHP;
};
```

And then lower in the "database" file:

```
struct monster starfish;

starfish.monsterName = "starfish";
starfish.maxMonsterHP = 5;
```

My question is, in my "main" file, how do I call upon these values and work with them, like so?

```
void monsterAttack(starfish)
{
    cout << "A " << monsterName << "is attacking!" << endl;
    cout << maxMonsterHP;
}
```

The "database" file has multiple different monsters that follow this structure, and I want the code in main to be able to work with all of them.

Comment: You would need a .h file that contains the `struct monster` definition and `#include` the header from your two `.cpp` files.

Comment: and an `extern struct monster starfish;` in the database header to allow main to see `starfish`. But instead may I offer `std::map<std::string, monster> monsters;` as an alternative one-stop shop for all your monster needs? Usage would be `monsters["starfish"]` to get a starfish or `monsters["Otyugh"]` to get an Otyugh. All you need to pass around is `monsters` in this case rather than hordes of individual monsters.

Comment: @zneak I made a header file that contains the class, "myheader.h", then I put `#include "myheader.h"` in both the main and database files. How do I call on the database values to use them in a function in main?

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations on taking the plunge to learn C++, as you gain experience, it will open your mind to a whole new way of thinking.

For a C++ beginner there are several hints which can help you get on your way. C++ is an object-orientated language. There are general agreed upon sets of principles and best practices that apply to all object-oriented languages. For your example it might seem unnecessary, but as your projects grow in size, scope, and complexity, especially if you want to create a real game, certain practices and ways of thinking are a must.

Your question deals with one of core principles of object-orientated software design.

The `struct` and `class` keywords in C++ exist for the purpose of encapsulation into objects. It is generally a good practice to group **related behaviour** and **related data** into reasonably-sized classes or structs of source code.

C++ programmers will typically place object **definitions** in the *.hpp* or *.h* header file. This is where you define the structure of an object, and declare *member* variables and functions. Then where you use the object, in your case your `main()` function, you would include the definition of your object with
`#include "YourClass.hpp"`.

The other file extension you will commonly see is the *.cpp* which is where the object **implementation** lives. In order to implement the behaviour of your object, you need to tell the compiler to include the object's header with `#include "YourClass.hpp"` at the top of your *.cpp* file.

This practice is called **separating definition from implementation**. You will find this process improves readability, and also improves compilation, because this is how the language is designed to be used.

**Summary:**

**Define** your object in the *definition header* file *.hpp*

**Implement** your objects behaviour in the *implementation* file *.cpp*

**Bold:**

Here is a rough skeleton of a class or struct that follows this.

```cpp
// -- your 'MyClass.hpp' file

class MyClass
{

private:

    // private member variables go here ( invisible from outside )

    float bar;

    int foo;

public:

    // these are your public member functions

    // the first two functions are the constructor and destructor
    // they get called when the object is created and destroyed
    // respectively

    MyClass();
    ~MyClass();

    // other member functions go here

    int fooFunction( float someArg );

    // ...etc

private:

    // private member functions go here

    void someOtherFunction();

    // ...etc

}
```

Then your *.cpp* implementation file looks like this.

```cpp
// -- your 'MyClass.cpp' file --


#include "MyClass.hpp"

// constructor function implementation
MyClass::MyClass()
{

    // put code that happens when the object is created

    foo = 12.0f;

    std::cout << "Object 'MyClass' created!" << std::endl;

}

// destructor function implementation
MyClass::~MyClass()
{

    // put code that happens when the object is destroyed

    std::cout << "Object 'MyClass' destroyed!" << std::endl;

}

int MyClass::fooFunction( float someArg )
{

    foo = someArg;

}

void MyClass::someOtherFunction()
{

    // do something

}
```

I realize you just started learning C++, but my advice to you would be to first pick up a few good introductory books on C++. I really like [C++ Primer 5th Edition](https://www.amazon.ca/Primer-5th-Stanley-B-Lippman/dp/0321714113/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1475542897&sr=8-1&keywords=c%2B%2B%20primer). Then you should familiarize yourself with general OPP coding practices.

When you feel comfortable with thinking in **patterns** and are serious about game development, take a look at [Game Engine Architecture, 2nd](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1466560010) and [Game Coding Complete, 4th][3].

It will save you a lot of time and headache by taking a methodical approach to learning programming and C++ in general. The internet is full of many great resources for people like you. Good luck!

Comment: You don't declare an object in a header. You define the class in the header and you declare/instantiate in the .cpp file.